# ServiceProvider binded class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

**Case (L5.4)**
Currently trying to write an api wrapper using the [package development](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages) Laravel offers.

I got a `ServiceProvider` which binds the model (`Niki::class`)

```
class NikiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/config/niki.php' => config_path('niki.php'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('niki', function () {
            return new Niki;
        });
    }
}
```

A `Facade` which registers the name of the component

```
class Facade extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'niki';
    }
}
```

And a `model`

```
class Niki extends Model
{
    /**
     *  Config
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->config = config('niki')['api_key'];
    }

    public static function getHouses()
    {        
        $response = $this->config;

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Above files are located in `packages/prsc/niki/src` and are being loaded using the psr-4 autoloading:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "PRSC\\Niki\\": "packages/prsc/niki/src/"
},
```

**Error**
So now my problem, the bind in the ServiceProvider returns a FatalError because of the file not being found.

> FatalThrowableError in NikiServiceProvider.php line 37: Class
>   'PRSC\Niki' not found

Comment: Can you please show your namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a namespace problem. I'm not sure I have all the clue about your namespaces, but here is something that should work (if I did not misunderstood):

Replace:

```
return new Niki;
```

By:

```
return new \PRSC\Niki\Niki;
```

If it does not work, please add your namespaces in each code snippet you pasted.